# What Android apps use C2DM push notifications?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

It doesn't seem that the official push notification service for Android, C2DM, is widely used nowadays. As required by a study on push notification, I would like to collect some existing apps that use Android's push notification. Do you know any major vendors using it except for Google services? I can only find Facebook and Yahoo Mail at this point.

Answer (score 0):

There are only a few using it for production purposes that I know of ... and I'm not aware of a list that includes all customers.  An issue is the fact that it requires Google's servers .. many of my clients needs systems and technology that they can control completely (too many problems otherwise, in their opinions).

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this permission for hint..
"com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"